# How to create chef recipe to create database and create tables in oracle DB

Tags: oracle11g, chef-infra, solaris, chef-recipe, cookbook

I'm new to oracle DB and chef. I had created a environment of Solaris OS and installed Oracle 11G DB in that environment using vagrantfile. Now i need to create a database and create tables in that database using chef.

Kindly guide me to proceed.

Comment: In chef, i had done the installation of apache , nginx and updating the index.html file and starting the services/

Comment: I haven't found so much when [searching the supermarket for 'oracle'](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks?order=recently_updated&platforms%5B%5D=&q=oracle). You might have a look at the [database](http://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/database) cookbook, how this does it for other RDBMSs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer whenever you ask "How do I do X with Chef?" the answer is "How would you do X without Chef? Then do that in recipe code.". Still applies here.